# Microsoft Graph SDK C# Newtonsoft.Json: Error reading JObject from JsonReader

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I want to get the count for direct user membership of a group.
This can be achieved with [Advanced Queries](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/identity/blogs/microsoft-graph-advanced-queries-for-directory-objects-are-now-generally-available/). I'm using the Microsoft Graph SDK and this code to request it:

```
var url = client
  .Groups[groupId]
  .Members
  .AppendSegmentToRequestUrl("microsoft.graph.user/$count");

var requestbuilder = new GroupRequestBuilder(url, client);

var result = await requestbuilder
  .Request()
  .Header("ConsistencyLevel", "eventual")
  .GetAsync();
```

It should be the equivalent of this URL:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/<groupId>/members/microsoft.graph.user/$count
```

with the header:

```
ConsistencyLevel = eventual
```

The request seems to go okay, but the response only includes the count in plain text. This is why JsonReader is throwing an error I think.
So how can I get only this plain text result value?

I've tried adding select to the query to skip the JsonReader, but the lambda only accepts group properties...

```
await requestbuilder
  .Request()
  .Header("ConsistencyLevel", "eventual")
  .Select(x => new { x })
  .GetAsync();
```

Comment: I ran that query in [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) and it returns text/plain, not application/json. So, don't try to deserialize it with JSON.NET, just read it as a string

Comment: @Crowcoder I described that in my question already. The question is how to instruct the C# SDK not to deserialize the response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by going trough the Microsoft.Graph.Core sourcecode and docs.
A reponse message is always deserialized what causes the problem in my case.

I've created a custom `IResponseHandler` for a text/plain response message:

```
    public class GraphPlainTextResponseHandler : IResponseHandler
    {
        public async Task<T> HandleResponse<T>(HttpResponseMessage response)
        {
            //Throw error if reponse is not successful
            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode) throw new HttpResponseException(response.StatusCode);
            //Throw error if response content-type is not of type text/plain
            if (response.Content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType != "text/plain") throw new InvalidOperationException($"Incorrect Content-Type: {response.Content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType}");

            return (T)Convert.ChangeType(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(), typeof(T));

        }
    }
```

Then I created the request with this code:

```
var url = client.Groups[groupId].Members.AppendSegmentToRequestUrl("microsoft.graph.user/$count");
            var baseRequest = new BaseRequest(url, client).WithResponseHandler(new GraphPlainTextResponseHandler());
            baseRequest.Header("ConsistencyLevel", "eventual");
            
            var result = await baseRequest.SendAsync<string>(null, CancellationToken.None);
```